# [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Value can not be converted to requested type

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008

In my project i have used Microsoft SQLServer 2008 for creating database schema.My project is working fine in Microsoft SQLServer 2008.But when i put the same schema to Microsoft SQLServer 2000 i get the below exception and my hibernate queries are not executed.Below is the list of exceptions.

```
could not read column value from result set: actualSt3_9_0_; [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Value can not be converted to requested type.
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: HY000
[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Value can not be converted to requested type.
[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Database changed to TimeSheet_Test
[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Changed database context to 'TimeSheet_Test'.
[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Language changed to us_english
[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Changed language setting to us_english.
Messagecould not execute query
```

Below is the driver i am used in [Microsoft][SQLServer 2008

```
database.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

How to fix this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is the query and what is the table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going back from MS SQL 2008 to 2000, there is a column with a data type that IS supported in 2008 and IS NOT supported in 2000.  For example "Date" data type.